# Rotman Algebraic Topology Theorem 3.2(ii)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand Theorem 3.2(ii) (I understand the other parts):

## Theorem

[image]

## Proof

[image]

## Questions

1. Question 1
   If I understand correctly, Rotman is trying to identify the path $f : I \rightarrow X$ with the affine map $[0, 1/2] \rightarrow [1/4, 1]$ (similar for $g, h$). How can we make these identifications?

Assuming this is true, I'm not sure how to find an explicit homotopy $H : I \times I \rightarrow X$ with $H: f * (g*h) \simeq (f*g) *h~\text{rel}~\dot I$.

2. Question 2.
   I also don't understand Rotman's remark after the proof:

> The groupoid in Theorem 3.2 is not a group because multiplication is not always defined; we remedy this defect in the most naive possible way, namely, by restricting our attention to closed paths.

If we're dealing with paths that otherwise agree on the start and endpoint, in which instances would multiplication be undefined?

## Update

#### Question 1

Here is my attempt at a homotopy, using the approach of the proof in 3.2(i).
[image]

I can see that this is incorrect, because we don't have the desired functions at $ t = 0$ and $t = 1$, for example. Can someone provide the correct homotopy/point out my error?

#### Question 2:

Thanks to advice from `Арсений Кряжев is with Ukraine`, I now see that, if $f * g$ and $g * f$ are defined, this forces both to be closed loops.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, he means that a path $I \to X$ can be seen as a map from $[0, t] \to X$ for any positive $t$ (by changing the "speed" with which one goes along the segment), or, more generally, from any nonempty interval $[a,b]$. The picture says that on the top of $I \times I$ we map accordingly $[0,1/4]$ to $X$ via $f$, $[1/4,1/2]$ via $g$ and so on, on the bottom we map $[0,1/2] \to X$ via $f$ and so on, and the in-between horizontal sections of $I \times I$ are mapped as depicted, e.g. the middle one is mapped via $f$ on $[0, \frac{1/4+1/2}{2}], $ via $g$ on $[\frac{1/4+1/2}{2}, \frac{1/2+3/4}{2}]$ and so on.
2. In a group any two elements can be multiplied, whereas in the fundamental groupoid this is only possible for paths whose endpoints agree.

Comment: 1. Your points are very clear, but I don't see how to calculate an explicit homotopy using this information -- can you provide the homotopy, which presumably uses an affine transformation for each line? 2. I understand that we need disparate path classes to agree on start and endpoint -- there are surely less strict requirements than dealing with closed paths, but this condition suffices.

Comment: 1. The map constructed _is_ the homotopy. 2. To multiply any path by itself one needs that this path is a loop. So this is necessary.